# random number not changing on submit in React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built a travel journal however I ran into two big bugs, one of them where the id which is set to Math.random()*10000 and is expected to change on submit however it does not, another issue I have is where  once I remove one journal entry, I am not able to add any more entries via submit.

I have tried adding the math.random in different places however it doesn't change, I have run out of ideas on how to tackle this issue, if you have any suggestions ,any help is appreciated.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import data from "./data";

function Entry(props) {
  const [entry, setEntry] = useState([
    {
      title: "",
      location: "",
      googleMapsUrl: "",
      startDate: "",
      endDate: "",
      description: "",
      imageUrl: "",
      id: Math.random() * 100000000,
    },
  ]);
  function handleChange(e) {
    setEntry((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      };
    });
  }

  // const newData = [...data];

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    setEntry((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
      };
    });

    data.unshift(entry);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="entry-form">
        <h1 className="entry-title">Add another Travel Memory</h1>
        <div className="journal-entry">
          <input
            className="entry-input"
            type="text"
            value={entry.location}
            name="location"
            placeholder="LOCATION"
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
          />

          <input
            className="entry-input"
            type="text"
            name="title"
            value={entry.title}
            placeholder="LANDMARK"
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
          />
          <input
            className="entry-input"
            type="text"
            name="googleMapsUrl"
            value={entry.googleMapsUrl}
            placeholder="GOOGLE MAPS LINK"
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
          />

          <input
            className="entry-input"
            type="date"
            value={entry.startDate}
            name="startDate"
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
          />
          <input
            className="entry-input"
            type="date"
            value={entry.endDate}
            name="endDate"
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
          />
          <textarea
            className="entry-input"
            placeholder="ADD YOUR STORY OR A FUN FACT FROM  YOUR JOURNEY"
            name="description"
            value={entry.description}
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
          />
          <input
            className="entry-input"
            type="text"
            name="imageUrl"
            value={entry.imageUrl}
            placeholder="ADD A IMAGE LINK TO REMIND YOU OF YOUR TRAVEL"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} className="entry-btn">
            add your travel memory
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <Card data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Entry;
```

Comment: *"is expected to change on submit"* - Can you clarify this expectation?  What specific code is changing this value and what debugging observations have you made when testing that code?  The `handleSubmit` function appears to be just overwriting the state value with the exact same values that were already there.

Comment: @David the point of change on submit was to provide unique ID to each travel entry, however what I have noticed is that no matter where the Math.random is sitting it doesn't change, I am fairly new so I might be missing some sort of understanding here.

Comment: @David thank you for the explanation, now that you explained the process it makes sense like day and night, it was my placement that pretty much cancelled my random number generation

Comment: You shouldn't expect random number to be unique, duplicates may happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Math.random()*10000 and is expected to change on submit however it does not

Because no code was written to change it.  Take a look at the state update in the submit handler:

```
setEntry((prevState) => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
  };
});
```

No values are changed.  The new state is an exact copy of the previous state.  Contrast this with the state update in the change handler for the input fields:

```
setEntry((prevState) => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  };
});
```

Notice how the new state is constructed from the previous state, *and a given field is updated*.

If you want to update the `id` field in the submit handler, update the `id` field in the submit handler:

```
setEntry((prevState) => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    id: Math.random() * 100000000
  };
});
```